# netbeans c auto popup code completion

Tags: c, netbeans

I'm using Netbeans 7 to program C.

Imagine if I type `prin` and `CTRL+SPACE` a popup window will come up with the `printf` suggestion.

How can I make this popup to show as I type? I don't want to use `CTRL+SPACE`.

Comment: Im looking for the same awnser

Comment: Doesn't seem to be possible. I'd recommend posting a bug on their Bugzilla. http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/enter_bug.cgi Personally I'm fine with pressing CTRL+SPACE though as the auto complete window tend to always pop up in the worst possible place, hiding as much important code as possible.

Comment: Yeah, I'd love to have that window automatically, too.

Answer (score 12):

If you have Netbeans with the [C/C++ plugin](https://netbeans.org/features/cpp/) installed, you can go to `Tools -> Options -> Editor -> Code Completion`.

Switch the Language drop down to C/C++.  You can then modify the Auto Popup Triggers for C/C++ Identifiers to something like this:

```
.;->;.*;->*;::;new ; ;a;b;c;d;e;f;g;h;i;j;k;l;m;n;o;p;q;r;s;t;u;v;w;x;y;z;
```

This will cause the auto completion window to popup once any of the above patterns are entered. Tested in Netbeans 8.0.2 works like a charm for me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using netbeans with Java, but it may work the same way. It should be possible to enable autocomplete for C as well. Check Tools -> Options -> Editor -> Code completion. If it's disabled, you can invoke it with Ctrl + Space. When enabled it should pop up automatically. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

### Anything language auto popup using "tab key"

Goto -> Tools -> Options -> Keymap -> 'completion' search in "search :" box.

click on [...] under 'shortcut' column where 'Actions' "Show Code Completion Popup" -> edit -> press tab -> press 'ok'

Now check and when editing.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what was said above by @Mike Kuenzi
the auto completion code you should paste in you Tools->Options->Editor->Code Completion. Select the language C/C++, copy the below code

```
.;->;.*;->*;::;new ; ;a;b;c;d;e;f;g;h;i;j;k;l;m;n;o;p;q;r;s;t;u;v;w;x;y;z;A;B;C;D;E;F;G;H;I;J;K;M;N;L;O;P;Q;R;S;T;U;V;W;Y;Z;
```

and paste it at ***Auto Popup Triggers for C/C++ identifiers***. Make sure to empty the space before pasting the data. Select the auto insert.

Please not that this will not work if you don't have the C/C++ plugin installed in your computer and have it configured for your Netbeans IDE.

I just tried it and it worked.