# How to make NetBeans autocomplete variable names in C++?

Tags: c++, netbeans, autocomplete, environment

NetBeans has a great autocomplete, when I type a dot I get all possible methods. But when I'm typing a variable name I have to press CTRL+Space. How to automate it?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/33748393/5566323
The solution is to add `;a;b;c;d;e;f;g;h;i;j;k;l;m;n;o;p;q;r;s;t;u;v;w;x;y;z;` on the end of Popup Triggers:
[As shown in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzJgj.png)